# app sends POST request twice

Tags: javascript, android, iphone, node.js, post

I'm using this code to send POST req to my server. For some reason, clicking the button sends two POST requests. The first one is sent as `/register/username/password`. The second one is sent to `/register`. The problem is that the second request always returns me 404.

I was trying to solve it with the `postCount` condition, but it still sends two requests.
It seems that when using chrome on windows or android-it ignores the 404 it works just fine. The problem is when using mac or iOS it throws me "Cannot POST /register" (because of the 404).

[This is the link to the app in Heroku](https://intense-beach-11390.herokuapp.com/).

Example for double POST req logs:

```
2017-08-31T11:36:18.896946+00:00 app[web.1]: POST /register/O**R/pass 200 0.423 ms - 3
2017-08-31T11:36:18.939530+00:00 app[web.1]: POST / 404 0.770 ms - 140
```

Req code:

```
var postCount = 0;
$("#rgstnBtn").click(function () {
    var password = $("#password").val();
    var username = $("#username").val();
    if(postCount === 0) {
        if (username && password) {
            $.post("/register/" + username + "/" + password, function (data) {
                postCount++;
                // console.log("hi");
                var status = data;
                if (data === '500') {
                    location.reload();
                    alert("username already exists");
                } else {
                    window.parent.location = "/item"
                }
            });
        } else {
            refresh();
            alert('please insert valid user name and password');
        }
    }
    function refresh() {
        setTimeout(function () {
            location.reload()
        }, 10);
    }
});
```

Comment: Looks like you really like to trigger page reloads. I suspect another POST happening somewhere else on page load.

Comment: can you move the refresh function outside of the **$("#rgstnBtn").click** function and try again.

Comment: sorry, it is not helpful :(

Comment: add `$("#rgstnBtn").unbind('click')` before `$("#rgstnBtn").click(function () {`. Maybe you did declare it twice and then you have two click event trigger for a single click. In `refresh()` store the `return` of `setTimeout` into a `variable` and call `clearTimeout(var)` before to call `setTimeout`, maybe it's called more than once.

Comment: not helpful as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok guys, I still don't know what is the cause for the double POSTing but, i used this op and the problem was solved:

```
 $("#rgstnBtn").attr('disabled', 'disabled');
```

thanks for everyone

Answer (score 1):

I was having a similar issue. Though it doesn't seem necessary, I found that using `.preventDefault()` did the trick.